# Running python in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have download the VS 2017 Pre-release which has native Python support and am trying to write a script to invoke a REST method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import sys
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

class MyRest():
    def __init__(self):

     self.appliance = "192.168.1.100" 
     BASE_URL = 'https://%s/api/about"'
     self.base_url = BASE_URL % self.appliance
     ret = requests.get(self.base_url, verify=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    myRest = MyRest()

    print("Hello")
    print("=" * 79)
    print(ret)
    sleep(10)

  except Exception as ex:
    print ("Failed")
    print(ex)
    sys.exit(1)
```

When I try to run in VS I get the run window pop up for a split second then exit which means I have no idea if the code ran ok or not. If I run the same script in IDLE then I see the expected console output:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\data\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication1\myREST.py", line 5, in 
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3**

I have 2 main problems:

a) how to run this script from VC2017 to get the same output as opposed to contagiously having to switch to IDLE

b) how to import urllib3 - I have run pip install via VS2017 like I did for requests but despite this there is still an error saying module is not imported

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading urlib3 from [Christoph Gohlke's pre-built Windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and then installing the local package from within Visual Studio (not with pip). It should fix the B part of your issue.